# Favicon not showing up when they were before under same format cleared cache tried everything

Tags: html, favicon

I have been working on this for hours and it is getting me extremely frustrated since i feel it should be so simple. I had a favicon that worked but wasnt to my liking so i went to switch it out by simply deleting the old favicon and putting a new one in its place with the same name same location but it would not appear and i havnt been able to get another to appear since

this is the code im using didnt know how to get <> in post so replaced them with ()

(head)
(title)
example
(/title)
    example
(link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon")
(/head)

the favicon is a 16x16 ico. file i have tried renaming the favicon and and the href respectively. i have done a clean up of my pc and all unnecessary files i have tried changing the code to thing like "(link rel="icon" href="flavicon.ico" /)" and a million other possible variations to no avail. everytime i make a change i empty the browser cache just in case. I have also put the file in the root folder mostly but have tried relocating it and specifying that location, no luck. when i enter my url + /flavicon.ico it says file not found. I am working purely offline (dont have a webserver or anything) if this could effect it and am testing the code on ie and chrome. one thing to note is that ill delete all copies of previous favicons but when i redownload one and switch it between folders the icon will sometimes change between the correct one and previous icons i feel like this could be a clue to the problem. Could a virus or some wierd computer glitch cause this? Im new to making websites and coding and the answer may be so simple but i feel my isssue is very strange and nothing seems to work if anyone has a suggestion to fix this i would REALLY APPRECIATE IT!
(sorry for the long rambling post i just wanted people to see all the different variations i have tried)

Comment: Just really quick one to clear up something as you have a typo above, "(link rel="icon" href="flavicon.ico" /)" flavicon, and I just want you to check that as you may have missed in your frustration.  That said,  in Chrome you got the dev console open, under Application clear site data. Reload. Is the favicon being requested in the Network Pane?

Comment: yeah i thought favicon was called flavicon at first so i occasionally mix these up but i have the right spelling in my code and have not messed it up in the actual code for the most part so this is not an issue for sure and i went to application cleared the site data, reloaded then went to the network tab and no there is no request for the favicon ( sorry for the late response i fell asleep)

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest [Using This Site](http://www.favicon.cc/?action=import_request), it will give you a favicon url, just place it in your `<head>` tag. I use this on all of my sites and never have a problem. Feel free to ask questions in a comment.

Example:

```
<head>
<link href="data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAQAAEABAAoAQAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEABAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGxu/ABwQAwAAAPoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAAgAAIAAAAAAAICIAAAAAAAACIAAAAAAAAAIiAAAAAAAAICETAAAAAAIAAAEwAAAAAAAAARMAAAAAAAAAATAAAAAAAAAAEwAAAAAAAAABMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//wAAHn8AAIx/AADA/wAA4f8AAOD/AADAfwAAiD8AAJwfAAD+DwAA/wcAAP+DAAD/wwAA/+MAAP//AAD//wAA" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
```

Comment: This is one of the sites i have used already to generate favicons and it did work for me the first time with the current code (one listed in question) and file location im using but now it does not for whatever reason however im not seeing a favicon url anywhere just a download option

Comment: also just want to reiterate that this is local only if that could have anything to do with it

Comment: Ah, you have to upload the favicon to their site, making it free to use (if that's Ok) and scroll to near the bottom, you'll see the URL there.

Comment: Im not seeing what you are talking about I choose the file from my computer and press the upload button then i press download im not seeing any url near the bottom what am i doing wrong

Comment: Once you've selected your image and clicked "upload", scroll down the next page and click "Publish under an open license". It'll then ask you to sign up using an email and pw (they don't send spam emails, this is just to sign up) and your link should be on the next page.

Comment: I did this although im convinced its not necessary because when I did it the first time i put the favicon directly in the root folder and never made an account or published it yet it worked. I published it and tried putting it into  the root file didn't work, I then tried using their URL link, also didn't work.

Comment: I am fairly convinced now this issue has to do with what i mentioned in the original post about the favi changing symbols or icons as i change folders which may have something to do with a cache on my pc being corrupted / not deleting or something. This really really sucks because im just trying to get into this yet noone seems to be able to explain my issue :/

Comment: (I cleared the browser cache every time i tried something new)

Answer (score 0):

maybe u have to add ../ before flavico.ico
become ../flavico.ico